# I need to run this test of my NestJs application

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to do this test, for a simple function, but I can't. I posted my test code and error.

I tried to do it in several different ways but I was not successful.
I'm using NestJS CLI and the test using jestJs

```js
 // My coding
  
  createSession(login: string, password: string) {
    const search: UserEntity = this.users.find(
      (user: UserEntity) => user.cpf === login,
    );
    if (search) return search.senha === password;
    else throw new HttpException('UNAUTHORIZED', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }
  
// My test
  
  it('should retrieve getHello', async () => {
    await expect(
        service.createSession(mockLogin.login, mockLogin.password),
    ).rejects.toEqual(
      new HttpException('UNAUTHORIZED', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED),
    );
  });
  
  
  // The error
  
   ● LoginService › Get service › should retrieve getHello

    HttpException: UNAUTHORIZED

      22 |     );
      23 |     if (search) return search.senha === password;
    > 24 |     else throw new HttpException('UNAUTHORIZED', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
         |                ^
      25 |   }
      26 | }
      27 |
```

Comment: Please don;t use images of code, but rather code blocks with markdown formatting. Images of code are not searcable and make the issue harder to read and diagnose

Comment: do some debug. eg: add `console.log(this.users)` to your `createSession` method

Comment: The code is ok, I have the feedback from users, my problem is to make the HttpException mock.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as follows:

```js
    it('should retrieve', async () => {
      await expect(
        service.createSession(mockLogin.login, mockLogin.password),
      ).rejects.toThrow();
    });
```